# Is there an implementation of a map-like container, with a real number as a key, and where a set of objects can be retrieved by key range?

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers

A list or a vector of pairs can be used as such a container, but unless one uses some kind of index, the access time will be O(N). Are there available for c++ implementations of such a container with build-in indexing, so that the access time is O(log(N)) ?

Are there implementations where two or more real numbers can be used as a key? (still with faster than O(N) access time ) ?

Comment: Look up [interval tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_tree) and maybe its generalisation, [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A binary search tree could be the solution. You can find the lowest key and the highest key in the range in `O(log(N))` time. And retrieving the objects between should be `O(k)` (where `k` is the number of objects found) by simply traversing the tree.

The `std::map` should be a good place to start, use it together with `std::map::lower_bound` and `std::map::upper_bound` (both are guaranteed to have at most logarithmic complexity).